# How can I galvanically isolate 5V 1A DC power?

Tags: power-supply, power, opto-isolator, isolation

I want a circuit to pass on ~5V DC at ~1-2A, but galvanically isolate it. Can somebody help? THX

Comment: Buy a DC-to-DC converter a la Traco etc..

Comment: What kind of dc-dc converter isolates galvanically?

Comment: What exactly do you need help with, what do you have already? We don't throw designs at people.

Comment: @user282088, an "isolated" DC-DC converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What kind of dc-dc converter isolates galvanically?

Pretty much +90% of them.

If I look in [Farnell](http://uk.farnell.com/c/power-line-protection/power-supplies/dc-dc-converters) I see there are 5640 isolating types and about 400 non-isolating types: -

[image]

Common Suppliers: Traco_Power, XP Power, Murata, Artesyn, Recom, TDK_Lambda